# Verical tabs - unable to get selected tab dynamically

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system, aura-iteration

We have created vertical tabs using lightning:tabset but we could not able to put the icon on the lihgtning:tab . So we are converted lightning:tabs to vertical tabs.
But we are not able to capture the selected tab . Tried to capture the target using event.target, event.currenttarget but it is returning null.
Here is the sample code , please suggest me to resolve the issue.

```
  <div class="slds-vertical-tabs tab-wrapper" >
            <ul class="slds-vertical-tabs__nav" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.triggerItems}" var="triggerItem" indexVar="index">    
                    <aura:if isTrue="{!(triggerItem.Id != undefined)}"> 
                        <li label="{!triggerItem.Name}" id="{!triggerItem.Id}" class="{!index == 0 ? 'slds-vertical-tabs__nav-item slds-is-active' : 'slds-vertical-tabs__nav-item'}" title="{!triggerItem.Name}" role="presentation" selectedTabId="{!v.newSelTabId}">
                            <a data-id='{!triggerItem.Id}' class="slds-vertical-tabs__link" href="javascript:void(0)"   aura:id="tabId" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="slds-vertical-tabs-0" id="slds-vertical-tabs-0__nav" onclick="{!c.triggerItemClick}"> 
                                <span class="slds-vertical-tabs__left-icon">
                                    <img  class="moonIcon" src="{!($Resource.assets + '/assets/images/inactive.svg')}" alt="meaningful text" />
                                </span>
                                <span class="slds-truncate" title="{!triggerItem.Name}">{!triggerItem.Name}</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </aura:if>
                </aura:iteration>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

The code for the trigger item click method

```
 triggerItemClick:function(component, event) {

      console.log("event target===>>"+event.target);
      console.log("current target===>>"+ event.currentTarget);
  }
```

These consoles are returning null

Comment: Please share the JS code for triggerItemClick()

Comment: @subhasisKar Please check the code, I udated the code